# Is it possible to use knockout js in static blocks?

Tags: magento2, static-block, knockoutjs

I am working in Magento 2 static blocks. Inside the static block I want some content to be dynamic.

Is there any way to use knockout js in static block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Knockout can be used inside Static Block. 
Insert the below code in a static block and save. 
On frontend page load you can see the text is updated using KO.

```
<div data-bind="text: 'Hello World'"></div>
```